# How should questions that turn out to not be real questions be handled?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at [this Coffeescript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226198/why-is-the-on-click-event-being-triggered).

It initially looked like a very valid question with confusing behavior, but on further examination turned out to be due to a syntax error that wasn't shown in the relevant code segment.  Its now sitting out as one of the most recent coffeescript questions, with no answers and no real purpose.

As a member of the community should I flag a question like this to be closed?  Encourage the original questioner to delete the question?  It doesn't seem to serve much purpose or add much value at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, the  best you can do at your current rep is to flag the question and downvote.

Once you reach 3000, rep, however, you'll be able to vote to close the question.  from your description, it sounds like the question should be closed as **too localized**